# Most efficient way to download multiple images

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am wondering what is the fastest way to download up to 10 images, each from a url and save them to the app.

Can they all be downloaded at once or do they have to be done one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Use NSURLSession in conjunction to  NSURLSessionDownloadTask. Start multiple tasks at once.